# Ansible EC2_ASG module failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, autoscaling

I am trying to create an AWS EC2 Auto-Scaling Group using the cloud module ec2_asg.

I have a playbook that is creating Security Groups, Elastic Load Balancer, Launch Config, tags the assets, etc.  Everything is working.  When I try to create a new ASG, I am getting a failure.  Below is the playbook code, and then the -vvv output of the module failure.  I am running ansible 2.2.1.0
Any help in troubleshooting is greatly appreciated

```
#setup Logstash Autoscaling group
- name: ELkstack LogStash ASG
  ec2_asg:
    name: "pro-ELK-LogStash-ASG"
    launch_config_name:  "test-test-asg"
    health_check_period: 300
    health_check_type: EC2
    replace_all_instances: yes
    replace_batch_size: 1
    min_size: 1
    max_size: 4
    desired_capacity: 1
    region: us-east-1
```

-vvv Error Output

```
    An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/folders/08/x2n75q_925l5xc9hfjc1gz9c0000gn/T/ansible_38fX0z/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py", line 875, in <module>
main()
    File "/var/folders/08/x2n75q_925l5xc9hfjc1gz9c0000gn/T/ansible_38fX0z/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py", line 864, in main
create_changed, asg_properties=create_autoscaling_group(connection, module)
    File "/var/folders/08/x2n75q_925l5xc9hfjc1gz9c0000gn/T/ansible_38fX0z/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py", line 437, in create_autoscaling_group
launch_config=launch_configs[0],
IndexError: list index out of range

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"failed": true,
"invocation": {
    "module_name": "ec2_asg"
},
"module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/08/x2n75q_925l5xc9hfjc1gz9c0000gn/T/ansible_38fX0z/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py\", line 875, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/var/folders/08/x2n75q_925l5xc9hfjc1gz9c0000gn/T/ansible_38fX0z/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py\", line 864, in main\n    create_changed, asg_properties=create_autoscaling_group(connection, module)\n  File \"/var/folders/08/x2n75q_925l5xc9hfjc1gz9c0000gn/T/ansible_38fX0z/ansible_module_ec2_asg.py\", line 437, in create_autoscaling_group\n    launch_config=launch_configs[0],\nIndexError: list index out of range\n",
"module_stdout": "",
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a spacing issue, feel dumb, but wanted to post to close this out and in case anyone else runs into this.